Laravel pagination - How to hide next button at the end
Using Laravel's pagination. It is working but when it gets to the last page it shows both the previous and next button. Is there a way to hid the "next" button?
public function index() {
     
       $posts = Post::orderBy('created_at', 'desc')->paginate(10);
       return view('posts.index', compact('posts'));
    }

  
 @foreach ($posts as $post) 
  {{$post->title}}
 @endforeach
 {!! $posts->links() !!} 


{{ $posts->onEachSide(2)->links() }}


Yes, you can hide the "next" button on the last page in Laravel pagination by customizing the pagination links. Laravel's default pagination views provide a way to conditionally display the next and previous buttons. You can create a custom pagination view and modify it to hide the "next" button on the last page.

First, publish the pagination views to your resources/views/vendor directory.
Modify the Pagination View
Open the resources/views/vendor/pagination/default.blade.php file (or another view file if you're using a different style).

Locate the section that renders the "Next" button and add a condition to check if it's the last page.
3. Use the Custom Pagination View
{!! $posts->links('vendor.pagination.default') !!}

Just use CSS to hide it because on the first page and last page you can't click on it.
Based on Laravel template default Tailwind CSS framework. For example:
nav[role='navigation'] > div > div span[aria-disabled="true"]{
    display: none;
}

If you want to correct exactly the CSS selector, you should create a custom pagination view

I use tailwind. So I assume it knows I have it installed and uses the tailwind.blade file? Before I had just next and previous buttons. Now it has the two arrows and number of pages. So its meant to have it displayed and not active?

Yes, two types of templates are different HTML code. You just inspect the disable button (on the browser) to find its class and then add CSS to hide it. I edited the example code to fit with Tailwind

I am new to Laravel so I was confused with what files to edit. Now I see there is a resources/view/vendor  folder and there is an vendor folder that is not to be edited.

You should take a look at the Directory Structure in the document and you should put my css code in a css file. and the file should be in the "Public Directory"

Thanks. I think I will leave it like it is. I was just referring to the two vendor folders.
